# Create object in an ArrayList from textfile input in java

Tags: java

I have a text file of a list of Students that lists last name, first name, lab grade, project grade, and exam grade, for example:

```
Owens Will 46 54 56  
Smith John 44 77 99
```

I am trying to write a method that reads the textfile, uses each line to create a Student object and then adds that to an ArrayList of Students. A Student object consists of the first name, last name, lab, project, and exam grades.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();

public void ReadFile(String inputfile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File myFile = new File(inputfile);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        arraylist.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to create the Student object from the text file and then unsure of how to place the objects into the ArrayList?

EDIT:

Here's my Student class:

```
public class Student {
    // fields
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int labgrade;
    private int projectgrade;
    private int examgrade;
    private int totalgrade;

    // constructor
    public Student(String firstname, String lastname, int labgrade,
        int projectgrade, int examgrade) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.labgrade = labgrade;
        this.examgrade = examgrade;
        this.totalgrade = labgrade + projectgrade + examgrade;
    }

    // method
    public String toString() {
        String s = firstname + " " + lastname + " has a total grade of "  + totalgrade;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: How/where did you define the `Student` class?

Comment: [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @ScottHunter edited to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
public void ReadFile(String inputfile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
    File myFile = new File(inputfile);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        try {
            String[] line = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

            arraylist.add(new Student(line[1], line[0], Integer.parseInt(line[2]), ...));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error of some kind...");
            continue; // maybe, I dunno.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: index 1 first then index 0 (since it is opposite last name first name)

Answer (score 1):

use split function

```
String line = sc.nextLine();
String[] student = line.split(" ");
String lastName = student[0];
String firstName = student[1];
String labGrade = student[2];
String projectGrade = student[3];
String examGrade = student[4];
```

or `new Student(student[0],student[1],student[2],student[3],student[4])`
the function split in String object will split any substring containing empty space like the above example. You could choose to split for example comma "," in CSV file using `String[] student = line.split(",");` but in this case it is empty space. Split will return an array of string

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```
private ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();

public void ReadFile(String inputfile) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    File myFile = new File(inputfile);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        String[] stdinfo = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        arraylist.add(new Student(stdinfo[1], stdinfo[0], Integer.parseInt(stdinfo[2]), Integer.parseInt(stdinfo[3]), Integer.parseInt(stdinfo[4])));
    }

}
```